# Matching different column from different table in DQS

Tags: mysql

I am working in retailer company where I have to match two column from different table. In this I have to match Item desc to Items desc. I put sample description below. To gives its new id number or sku.

**Table1 DEsc**

```
KILZ ORIGINAL PRIMER QT
PNTBRSH XL CUB 2"
PAINTBRSH UTILITY 1"POLY
ELBOW SERV ENT SLB 3/4"
COUPLNG 1/4"FPT BRS LL
```

**Table2 DECS**

```
Kilz Original, QT, Oil Based.
2", XL Cub Angular Sash.
1", Polyester, Varnish Utility Brush.
3/4" Service Entrance
1/4", Brass Coupling, Lead
```

What kind of domain I have to create to match this kind of description?

Is it possible to match from different table in DQS?

Answer (score 0):

If the columns of data you showed are all you have, it's going to be quite difficult to match rows from these two tables.

You're going to need a table of term synonyms. This table will match terms like *BRUSH* to "Paintbrush" and "BRS" to "Brass".

Then you're going to need a scoring system of some kind, to allow you to determine the best matches.